# Digest Authentication with Google Apps Scripts using UrlFetch

Tags: google-apps-script, digest-authentication

I'm trying to access a URL that is protected by Digest Authentication, using UrlFetch of Google Apps Script.

I managed to access a URL using Basic Authentication:

```
 var options =
{
  "method" : "get",
  "headers" : {
    "Authorization" : "Basic <Base64 of user:password>"  
  },
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.example.com/service/using/basic", options);
```

and I managed to access with OAuth based on the [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp) in the documentation.

The problem now is that I need to have the same functionality with a site that is implementing Digest. I can access it with the following curl:

```
curl -v --digest --user user:password http://www.example.com/service/using/digest
```

**Updated**

If I try to simply call

```
var options =
{
  "method" : "get",
  "headers" : {
    "Authorization" : "Digest " + Utilities.base64Encode( Utilities.computeDigest(user:password) )
  },
};
```

It doesn't work due to the Challenge-Response mechanism of Digest Authentication.

Can I have it with UrlFetch using any JavaScript library that is implementing such functionality? or directly by UrlFetch itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Digest authorization is a bit more complicated then what you have so far. Check out the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) or look at this [sample Python implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302378-digest-authentication/) for more information.

It should be possible to implement digest auth with Apps Script, using the Utilities methods that Henrique mentioned. As for handling the challenge/response portion of the algorithm, you can use the not-yet-documented UrlFetchApp option `muteHttpExceptions` as [shown here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1202#c2).

Answer (score 0):

There's the bulti-in [Utilities.computeDigest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#computeDigest) and [base64Encode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities.html#base64Encode). Which are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I have no problem of getting the MD5 or other digest values. The problem is with the challenge protocol of the Digest authentication. I need to be able to receive a response from the server and reply with digest of the the server challenge and the credentials of the user, to be able to authenticate.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I did not understood you question indeed, and still can't understand. Anyway, I'm not going to delete my answer now, just to avoid other people with the same misunderstanding to give the same answer again.

Comment: I've updated the question based on your answer, to try to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. An implementation of the digest auth in Google Sheet Script:

```
function fetchDataWithDigestAuth() {
  var apiUrl = "url"; // Replace with your API endpoint
  var username = "your_username"; // Replace with your API username
  var password = "your_password"; // Replace with your API password

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  console.log("response.getResponseCode()" + response.getResponseCode());
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 401) {
    var authHeader = response.getHeaders()["WWW-Authenticate"];
    var digestAuth = createDigestAuth(username, password, authHeader);

    var options = {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Authorization": digestAuth },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
  }

  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // Process the response data as needed
  Logger.log(data);
}

function createDigestAuth(username, password, authHeader) {
  var realm = extractHeaderValue(authHeader, "realm");
  var nonce = extractHeaderValue(authHeader, "nonce");
  var uri = extractHeaderValue(authHeader, "uri");
  var qop = extractHeaderValue(authHeader, "qop");
  var nc = "00000001";
  var cnonce = Utilities.getUuid();

  var ha1 = Utilities.computeDigest(
    Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5,
    username + ":" + realm + ":" + password
  );
  var ha2 = Utilities.computeDigest(
    Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5,
    "GET:" + uri
  );

  var testString = ha1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + nc + ":" + cnonce + ":" + qop + ":" + ha2;

  var response = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, testString)
    .map(function (chr) { return (chr + 256).toString(16).slice(-2) })
    .join('')

  var digestAuth =
    'Digest username="' + username + '", ' +
    'realm="' + realm + '", ' +
    'nonce="' + nonce + '", ' +
    'uri="' + uri + '", ' +
    'qop=' + qop + ', ' +
    'nc=' + nc + ', ' +
    'cnonce="' + cnonce + '", ' +
    'response="' + response + '"';

  return digestAuth;
}

function extractHeaderValue(header, key) {
  var regex = new RegExp(key + '="(.*?)"', "i");
  var matches = header.match(regex);
  return matches ? matches[1] : '';
}
```